# boost function to any functor with template operator ()

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I want to store `boost::function<void(void*)>` in order to point to an arbitrary functor class object. I tried the following code, but it does not compile :

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T* a)
    {            
        T& ref = *a; 

    } 
};
struct MyFunctor2
{
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T* a)
    {            
        T& ref = *a; 

    } 
};

boost::function<void(void*)> anyFunctorPtr;
anyFunctorPtr= MyFunctor();
double a = 5;   
anyFunctorPtr(&a);
```

The compiler error is error C2182: 'ref' : illegal use of type 'void'

Comment: By using `void(void*)`, you are forcing template parameter `T` = `void`.

Comment: I see. :( Any other idea how to achieve the wanted generic function pointer

Comment: It's hard to say if you don't give more context. Maybe [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: VTC is unclear what is asked about.

Comment: Is there a known set of function signatures that this will be used with? In that case it would be possible to do what you need. Otherwise it is just not possible to push through the C++ type system.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::function`, just like `std::function` requires a specific functor signature (in your case `void(void*)`), which is the signature it will try to call your functor with. That's why `T` is deduced as `void` and the compiler refuses to give you a `void&`, rightfully so.

Your example is fundamentally add odds with itself, because if you want to have type erasure, you cannot have templates, as the compiler cannot know which templates to instantiate otherwise. Assume for a moment that `boost::function<magic>` could do what you want.

If you give the compiler code like this:

```
void foo(boost::function<magic> func)
{
    double a = 5;   
    func(&a);
}
```

How would the compiler know whether to generate a `T = double` instantiation for `MyFunctor` or `MyFunctor2`? It simply cannot know, and thus it cannot generate the right code. There is no limit on the amount of templated functor classes you can have and the number of types you can attempt to call `operator()` with, so instantiating them automatically ahead of time is also out of the question.